# Generic Wix Installer for multiple projects

Tags: c#, wix, visual-studio-2013, wix3.7, post-build-event

I am new to Wix so forgive me for any terms I may use incorrectly.

I have a large solution with many projects some of which become installable services, executables and what not. In the post build events of projects that will have an installer I run the following to generate a fragment containing all the files the installer will need.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\heat.exe" dir $(TargetDir) -ag -cg harvestedComponents -out $(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).wxs`

I want to create one single Wix setup project that has a component reference placeholder that I can then link to the fragment. This way I can reuse the functionality of the one setup project and not need a setup project for each installable item I have. From there I would have a second build event that would link/compile the fragment and project along with passing in flags to the generic installer project that could turn on/off install features, such as adding event source, different custom actions and such.

So my question is how do I link/compile a fragment with a generic Wix project from a post build event of the executable project. I am guessing it would look something like:

```
Candle/Light.exe fragment.wxs generic.wxs -eventLog true -customAction1 true -msiName MyInstaller.msi
```

Where I would use the values of eventLog customAction1 inside the generic file to enable/disable install features.

Sorry for the confusion and hope this is possible.

Comment: Don't forget each installer needs its own UpgradeCode and Version.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly you want to reference the fragment created by heat (`$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).wxs`) in your generic WiX source file?
If this is the case you just have to add a `ComponentGroupRef`-tag below your `Feature`-element (instead of a `ComponentRef`-element you would use normally). As `Id` for the elemenet you have to use the name of the `ComponentGroup` that you used in the heat-commandline, `harvestedComponents` in your example. E.g.

```
<Feature Id="MyFeature" ...>
    ...
    <ComponentRef Id="aNormalComponentFromTheCurrentFile" ... />
    ...
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="harvestedComponents" />
</Feature>
```

Or did I miss the point?

Comment: Yes this answers part of it, thanks. But I also am trying to figure out how to link the two files either using candle or light or something and pass along command line parameters to evaluate conditions in my generic file. Something that runs after heat that would look like "candle/light.exe fragment.wxs generic.wxs -eventLog true -custAction1 true" this may be two different commands not sure.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Do you mean to set properties on the commandline? If so, then you can always set a WiX-variable in the source files (e.g. $(wix.Eventlog)) and then set the value on the commandline, using -d<Name>=<Value>, e.g. -dEventlog=true.